# Reverse pyramid using same row number

Tags: c

I encountered the following [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw5S2.png) which ask you to print the reverse pyramid. Using same number as row number,all of my results are like reverse pyramid following (2i-1) number of terms in each row.

The other one is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, row;
    printf ("Enter the no of rows");
    scanf ("%d", &row);
    for (i = row; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            printf ("%d", i);
        }

        printf ("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

what changes should I make in the above program to get the desired result.

some homework which I did: searched several sites which explains C and has examples related to it. Closest which I could get was this 
http://www.techcrashcourse.com/2016/01/print-reverse-pyramid-star-pattern-in-c.html
Then added a new loop:
for(k=3;k<=row-i;k++);
printf("  ");
and changed the initial value of "K" several times but it did not work out.

Comment: edited what I could find till now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not particularly easy to guess what you had in mind, but regarding linked question, it should be done as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
    {
    int i , j, k, row;
    printf ("Enter the no of rows");
    scanf ("%d",&row);
    for (i=row;i>=1;i--)
    {
        for(k = 0;k<row - (i-1);k++)
        {
            printf (" ");
        }
        for (j=1;j<=i;j++)
        {
            printf ("%d",i);
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
        return 0;
}
```

also, next time please post your results.

Comment: thank you for the "K" loop i was entering the wrong values :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the question given in your link the answer is below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
    {
        int row,i,j,k;
        printf("Enter Number of Rows: ");
        scanf("%d",&row);
        for(i=row;i>0;i--){
            for(j=row-i;j>0;j--)
                printf(" ");
            for(k=1;k<=i+(i-1);k++)
                printf("*");
            printf("\n");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

The number of stars in a row is the sum of that row number and the previous one.
Ex: If the row number is 5, then number stars in that row is = 5+4 = 9.